# List element not encompassing entire ul

Tags: html, css

I have a simple list set up in a unordered list. I want the list element to span the entire width of the `ul` but I cannot seem to figure out why my approach isn't working.

I have attempted to apply:

```
nav ul li {
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0;
}
```

But that changes nothing. Even `width:100%;` to the `li` element does nothing. How can I get the list to span the width of the `unordered list`?

```css
.nav-container {
  border-right: 1px solid #E4E2E2;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f4f3f3;
}

.nav {
  text-align: justify;
}

nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.nav-link {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #f4f3f3;
}

.nav ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav ul li {
  margin-left: 5px;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 25px;
}

.nav ul li a {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.nav li:hover a {
  color: #f4f3f3;
}


/* QUERIES */

@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .nav-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f4f3f3;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid #f4f3f3;
  }
  .nav-link {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .logo-holder {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 40%;
  }
  .nav-container nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .logo-holder {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #navigation-div {
    background-color: #f4f3f3;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .hide {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav ul li {}
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <div class="logo-holder">
    <img class="user-select-none" src="test.jpeg" width="150px" height="150px" alt="temp" />
  </div>
  <div id="navigation-div">
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="nav-ul">
        <li><a class="nav-link active" href="">Test 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link " href="">Test 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Test 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: You can also see how when you hover over the empty space on the left of each link, the links turn white.

**Edit**:
Apologies, forgot to mention that when my screen resizes, my vertical nav bar will convert into a horizontal navbar. I have updated my code to display this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the left margin from the li and .nav-link:

```
.nav ul li,
.nav-link {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Note you're removing the margin on .nav-link here:

```
.nav-link {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

But you're adding it back in later.

```
.nav-link {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

A little tip for troubleshooting styling - if you're using Chrome, open the developer console, select your element and change the "styles" tab to "computed", and you'll be able to see specifically what styles are being applied to the element you're working with (and then trace them back to find out what is applying them). It makes it a little easier to troubleshoot when you have potentially multiple style declarations overwriting each other on the same element :)

Comment: Thanks for the handy tip too!

Comment: No worries. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You have a `margin-left: 15px` applied to `.nav-link`, which causes your issue, simply change it to a padding-left and remove the `margin-left` on `.nav li ul`, see this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/f2fc0r1q/

Answer (score 0):

**Your code using some duplication, it just needs a little tweaking.**

```css
.nav-container {
  background-color: #f4f3f3;
  border-right: 1px solid #E4E2E2;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
}

.nav {
  text-align: justify;
}

.nav ul {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 25px;
}

.nav-link {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
  line-height:15px;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #f4f3f3;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <div id="navigation-div">
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="nav-link active" href="">Test 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link " href="">Test 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Test 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as you `.nav-link` and  `.nav ul li` has `margin-left` value. By removing them or make them 0 will give you the desired output.

```css
.nav-container {
  border-right: 1px solid #E4E2E2;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f4f3f3;
}

.nav {
  text-align: justify;
}

.nav-link {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.nav ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav ul li {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 25px;
}

.nav-link {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #f4f3f3;
}

.nav li:hover a {
  color: #f4f3f3;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <div id="navigation-div">
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="nav-link active" href="">Test 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link " href="">Test 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Test 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```